# How to Drop dupicate row based on Two Columnn difference dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have Two daraframe and i try to drop the row have same value.
By I have a condition to drop that is a same value based on column[์Name] and column[Variable]

df1

```
data1 = {'No':['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6','A7','A8','A9','A10','A11','A12','A13'],
         'Name':['Red','Red','Green','Green','Blue','Blue','Yellow','Black','White','Red','Gray','Gray','Gray'],
         'Score':[0,1,2,3,4.6,0,0,0,2.7,2.7,7,7,10],
         'Variable':['A','B','A','B','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','C'],
         'Comment':['','','','Team A','','Team B','','','Team C ','','Team D','',''],
         'Note':['https:google.com','','https:google.com','','https:google.com','','','https:google.com',
                 'https:google.com','','https:google.com','','']
        } 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1) 

df1
```

output of df1

```
    No  Name    Score   Variable    Comment        Note
0   A1  Red     0.0        A                  https:google.com
1   A2  Red     1.0        B        
2   A3  Green   2.0        A                  https:google.com
3   A4  Green   3.0        B        Team A  
4   A5  Blue    4.6        A                  https:google.com
5   A6  Blue    0.0        A        Team B  
6   A7  Yellow  0.0        A        
7   A8  Black   0.0        A                  https:google.com
8   A9  White   2.7        A        Team C    https:google.com
9   A10 Red     2.7        A        
10  A11 Gray    7.0        A        Team D    https:google.com
11  A12 Gray    7.0        B           
12  A13 Gray    10.0       C
```

df2

```
data2 = {'Name':['Red','Blue','Yellow','Black','White'],
         'Variable':['A','A','A','A','A']
        } 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2) 

df2
```

out put of df2

```
Name    Variable
Red       A
Blue      A
Yellow    A
Black     A
White     A
```

Example I want df3

```
No  Name    Score   Variable  Comment    Note
A2  Red      1.0       B                 
A3  Green    2.0       A              https:google.com
A4  Green    3.0       B       Team a    
A11 Gray     7.0       A       Team d https:google.com
A12 Gray     7.0       B                 
A13 Gray    10.0       C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do `merge`

```
yourdf=df1.merge(df2,indicator=True,how='left').loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']
     No   Name  Score Variable Comment              Note     _merge
1    A2    Red    1.0        B                            left_only
2    A3  Green    2.0        A          https:google.com  left_only
3    A4  Green    3.0        B  Team A                    left_only
10  A11   Gray    7.0        A  Team D  https:google.com  left_only
11  A12   Gray    7.0        B                            left_only
12  A13   Gray   10.0        C                            left_only
```

Comment: Thanks You very much